# Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop Automatic Login Not Working

Tags: 12.04, auto-login

When I first installed Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop on this machine the auto login worked fine.  Now it does not.  I've run some Google searches and I've seen plenty of the typical go to Settings and unlock and ... to enable auto login.  But the setting is enabled and was working.

I suspect the issue has to do with having logged into KDE Plasma as the login screen is now the Plasma login instead of the original Unity one.  Originally the machine was running Unity3D (the default) but I couldn't get my VNC viewer to work so it was recommended that I use Unity2D.  However, before going to Unity2D I decided to try KDE Plasma.  I believe this is when the auto login stopped working - I wasn't paying attention to exactly when the auto-login stopped working because I was attempting to solve another more pressing problem.

From what I remember of the KDE install instructions it isn't as simple as `apt-get purge kde` to get rid of the KDE desktop.

Any thoughts on how to get the auto-login to work again? I have crons running under that user that could be made root crons but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to get rid of the KDE desktop as you mentioned, things should probably work again.

[Here's how, from the terminal -- copy and paste!](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get remove akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apport-kde apturl-kde ark bluedevil cdparanoia cdrdao cryptsetup docbook-xml docbook-xsl dolphin dragonplayer freespacenotifier gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm gpsd gstreamer0.10-qapt gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen gwenview ibus-qt4 icoutils jockey-kde k3b k3b-data kaccessible kaddressbook kamera kate kate-data katepart kcalc kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-config-gtk kde-config-touchpad kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-style-oxygen kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager kde-window-manager-common kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kde-zeroconf kdegames-card-data kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepasswd kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kdepim-strigi-plugins kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdesudo kdm kdoctools khelpcenter4 kinfocenter klipper kmag kmail kmenuedit kmix kmousetool knotes konsole kontact kopete kopete-message-indicator korganizer kpat kppp ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktimetracker ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-debug-installer kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-netbook-default-settings kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-web-shortcuts kvkbd kwalletmanager language-selector-kde libakonadi-calendar4 libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadi-notes4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libassuan0 libattica0.3 libbluedevil1 libboost-program-options1.46.1 libcalendarsupport4 libcln6 libclucene0ldbl libdebconf-kde0 libdlrestrictions1 libdmtx0a libencode-locale-perl libepub0 libeventviews4 libfile-listing-perl libflac++6 libfont-afm-perl libgadu3 libgif4 libgpgme++2 libgps20 libgrantlee-core0 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libibus-qt1 libilmbase6 libincidenceeditorsng4 libindicate-qt1 libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libk3b6 libkabc4 libkactivities-bin libkactivities6 libkalarmcal2 libkateinterfaces4 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcddb4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5 libkdecorations4 libkdecore5 libkdegames5a libkdepim4 libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdgantt2 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-10 libkexiv2-data libkfile4 libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkio5 libkipi-data libkipi8 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkleo4 libkmanagesieve4 libkmbox4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkontactinterface4 libkopete4 libkparts4 libkpgp4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libksba8 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4 libksieveui4 libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent3 libkunitconversion4 libkwineffects1abi3 libkwinglutils1 libkwinnvidiahack4 libkworkspace4abi1 libkxmlrpcclient4 liblastfm0 libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailcommon4 libmailtools-perl libmailtransport4 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4 libmicroblog4 libmpcdec6 libmsn0.3 libmuonprivate1 libmygpo-qt1 libmysqlclient18 libnepomuk4 libnepomukdatamanagement4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomuksync4 libnepomukutils4 libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libokularcore1abi1 libopenexr6 libotr2 libphonon4 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4abi3 libplasmagenericshell4 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-3 libprison0 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libqalculate5 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqjson0 libqrencode3 libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-qt3support libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtgstreamer-0.10-0 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtwebkit4 libreoffice-kde libreoffice-style-oxygen libsocket6-perl libsolid4 libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager4abi3 libtemplateparser4 libthreadweaver4 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl libvirtodbc0 libweather-ion6 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxml2-utils libxss1 libzip2 muon muon-installer muon-notifier muon-updater mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-icon-theme partitionmanager phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-menubar plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text polkit-kde-1 printer-applet python-kde4 python-pyudev python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-sip qapt-batch qapt-deb-installer quassel quassel-data rekonq sgml-data shared-desktop-ontologies software-properties-kde soprano-daemon system-config-printer-kde systemsettings tasks-icons update-manager-kde usb-creator-kde userconfig virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common xsettings-kde && sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Seems to be working...  I have run the command you provided on my machine and so far it appears to be working - not that I've extensively tested to see if any packages were broken in the process.  Howver, I will say that I needed to login/reboot several times before it seemed to settle out completely.  On my first logout/login it went to a terminal screen with no desktop.  Then I rebooted and it went to a Unity background but I never got any icons to appear (although Samba and VNC appeared to be working fine).  Then I rebooted again and choose Unity2D.  Then I rebooted again and it worked.